# textarea on vue not accepting null

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, yup, vee-validate

I use:
- "vue": "3.2.26",
- "vee-validate": "4.5.6",
- "typescript": "4.5.4"

While creating a textarea field on vue3 I ran into a problem

i have

example with vee-validate

```
import { Field, useForm } from 'vee-validate'

<Field v-slot="{ field, errors }" name="name" type="text">
<VControl icon="feather:edit-2" :has-error="Boolean(formErrors.name)">
<input
    v-bind="field"
    class="input is-primary-focus"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Placeholder"
    autocomplete="name"
    />
<p v-if="errors" class="help is-danger">{{ formErrors.name}}</p>
</VControl>
</Field>
```

simple example

```
<textarea
    v-model="fieldValues.description"
    class="textarea is-success-focus"
    rows="3"
    placeholder="Description"
></textarea>
```

for model

```
export interface iCat {
    id: number
    name: string
    description: string | null
}
```

but textarea return error

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
```

for vee-validate

```
const {
    values: fieldValues,
    errors: formErrors,
    handleSubmit,
} = useForm({
    initialValues: {
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        description: ''
    },
    validationSchema: object({
        id: number().required().integer(),
        name: string().required(),
        description: string().notRequired().default(null).nullable()
    }),
})
```

if check @vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.d.ts

```
export interface TextareaHTMLAttributes extends HTMLAttributes {
    ....
    value?: string | string[] | number
    ...
}
```

If I look in node-moduls, I see that the textarea does not accept null as a value - how can I properly solve this problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the existing type of `value` for `TextareaHTMLAttributes` (at least not in TypeScript 4.5.5). Type augmentation only allows extension (adding properties to the type, or creating a new type that extends the original `TextareaHTMLAttributes`  interface with a new type for `value`).

A workaround is to use a new type that extends `iCat`, changing its `description` type to the expected type of `TextareaHTMLAttributes`'s `value`:

1. Declare a new type (named `"iFieldValues"`), using [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to exclude the original `description` property from `iCat`, and an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) with a new `description` property that has a type of `TextareaHTMLAttributes['value']`.
2. Use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (`as iFieldValues`) on the `values` returned from `useForm()`.

```html
// MyForm.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { toRefs } from 'vue'
import type { TextareaHTMLAttributes } from '@vue/runtime-dom'
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate'
import { object, number, string } from 'yup'

export interface iCat {
    id: number
    name: string
    description: string | null
}
        1️⃣
type iFieldValues = Omit<iCat, 'description'> & {
  description: TextareaHTMLAttributes['value']
}

const {
    values,
    errors: formErrors,
    handleSubmit,
} = useForm({
    initialValues: {
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        description: ''
    },
    validationSchema: object({
      id: number().required().integer(),
      name: string().required(),
      description: string().notRequired().default(null).nullable()
    }),
  })
                                   2️⃣
const fieldValues = values as iFieldValues
</script>
```